# Apache Tomcat getting restarted

Tags: tomcat, java

We're running tomcat 6.0.35 on a Windows 2008 Server.

It runs out of memory every few days. We noticed in the logs that the server is getting reinitialized randomly.

We see this in the tomcat log.

[main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Starting service Catalina

And everytime it goes down, we see this warning message:

ERROR org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- The web application [/webconsole] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@38fc73ee]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

We figured that this could be an issue with the [log4j bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50486).

However, the bigger question is why is server getting reinitialized? We checked if there're some files changing that are being watched and thus causing the restart, but there're none.

Will appreciate if someone has any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the type of error message that gets logged when tomcat's memory leak detection/prevention gets tripped. The [MemoryLeakProtection](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) page on the Tomcat Wiki has more information on it.

You might be able to stop the re-initialization by disabling `autoDeploy` in the `Host` element of your `server.xml`. Tomcat ships by default with `autoDeploy` set to *true*.